# Cant add new xib's to view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xib

I am working on one view controller which has three static screens which i m going to show to user for first time when he installs the app, for next time forever i will show him main functional view.

Problem is

When i have created viewController class i never selected xib option.

Now i have added two xib's (iPhone and iPad) in project.First i deleted the present view from it then I have created three static views in each which contains some label and one button in each..

I want to add those views in my view controller's view. and i want to add targets for buttons in those view.

I am unable to reference outlets in my class for all three views
and can't add target for buttons in my viewController.

How can i do that??

Please help......

[image: here's my xib and view controller on which i working on]

Solved it..:)

Problem was when i have added new xib file to project.i deleted the present view controller view from xib...thats why xib was unable to find any of the projects view controllers in custom class drop down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the File's owner on the left while the XIB is opened:

[image]

Select the the third icon on the far right, and make sure the correct class is selected under Custom class, the green textfield:

[image]

Comment: Type out the name of your view controller class.

Comment: My view controllers name isn't present in drop down

Comment: Then type it out entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select File Owner then go to the identity inspector in right pan of Xcode where you can select yor Xib name :)

Comment: I know xib's name but how can I use views in my view controller